How do I use presence_of_element_located to click a checkbox
I want to use a piece of code like this:
elementspan = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(("xpath", '//span[text()="" and @class="cb-i"]')))

the trick is the html I am presented is below
I want to click the checkbox below,just not sure how to code the command above to hunt down and click the "checkbox"
<div class="cb-c" role="alert" style="display: flex;">
<label class="cb-lb">
<input type="checkbox">
<span class="cb-i"></span>
<span class="cb-lb-t">Verify you are human</span></label></div>


Edit your question to include a minimal, reproducible example.

You've chosen not to share the URL for the page you're working with so (just a guess) try: EC.element_to_be_clickable

If there's just one checkbox on the page, then you can use:
//input[@type='checkbox']

